# AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am trying to use *bcrypt* in my Flask app to check if my passwords match. But after running my code I get `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'password'` and it seems to me that it has some problem getting **password** from database but i don't know why.

Here is my code:

```py
auth = request.authorization
local_session = Session(bind=engine)
user = local_session.query(User).filter_by(email=auth.username)

if bcrypt.checkpw(auth.password.encode('utf-8'), user.password.encode('utf-8')):
   some stuff...
```

My databse:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    password = Column(String(100))
```

So I checked names of my column and name I use in code but it is the same. I really don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: `user` is still a query when it's being probed for a password. To turn it into a user, add `.scalar_or_one()` if you're using `flask_sqlalchemy`.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith no I only use `sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I didn't run the Query and it needs either `.all()` or `.first()`.

So in this situations it should look like this:

```py
user = local_session.query(User).filter_by(email=auth.username).first()
```

This solves the problem and works fine.